# How can i trigger a Telegram Bot via an API user

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

i've set up a working telegram bot that get's triggered on a `/mission` command. I want to use the bot within groups to enable a fast response feedback system for my organization. the flow is like follows:

1) a API client (no bot, just pure api) sends a message to a group, triggering the bot using `/mission` . 
2) the bot responds to the command and the feedback process starts..

As a normal user, I can trigger the bot whereas the api user won't even reach my bot using webhooks. 
Is there any known limitation on what APIs can trigger?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Telegram **MTProto API** has **same limits** and **same benefits** of a **normal Telegram user**. So, you can trigger all bots you want, but be careful with `FLOOD_WAIT` error: an user sends too much messages in one second or in one minute, Telegram blocks the user for x seconds.

If you don't want to setup tg-cli, and other stuff to run MTProto client on your server and control it, I suggest you to use [PWRTelegram APIs](https://pwrtelegram.xyz), so logging in as user.